# How to prevent closing of a HIDDEN form in C#

Tags: c#, formclosing

I want to prevent closing of a form in some cases. I know the usage of OnFormClosing,
but when the form is hidden (Visible==false), the OnFormClosing method is not called.
Is there a way to intercept form closing in this case?

Edit (some more details):
The form is a child in a MdiParent, should stay invisible in the background and wait for calls from another thread (by Invoke).

The MdiParent closes all child windows when the user "disconnects", in this case the above form should stay open, but invisible and still waiting for calls.
When the MidParent itself is closed, all forms should close.

Edit2 (no solution?):
It seems that there is no solution to this. My workaround now is to exclude my not-to-be-closed form in the MdiParent-code, that closes all other forms.

Comment: If it is hidden, how could the user closes it? or do you mean by a task-manager-like application?

Comment: If it is hidden, what is causing it to close? There must be some other action that is related to the closing that you can explicitely call some function of the form to to what you need to do. Otherwise, you should provide more info about the problem.

Comment: How and what is causing the hidden form to close ? please post in some details

Answer (score 2):

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
                // This will cancel the event
                e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Regardless of the reason, this will effectively stop a form from closing.

Comment: This is what I tried first and as long as the form is visible it works. But after `Form.Visible=false` the last method called is OnHandleDestroyed.

Comment: How are you closing the MdiChildren?

Comment: I close it in the MdiParent-Form with frmChild.Close(). I uploaded a minimal sample project [here](http://members.aon.at/warpenterprises/MdiTest.zip). When the child form is visible, no closing is possible. When the child form is hidden, it (and the MdiParent) can be closed.