# C# Hiding Window instead of closing

Tags: c#, hide, formclosing

I am attempting to intercept the close window but it seems to fail and close anyway for a form application. Essentially, this program should be waiting for input from a user on a signature pad and it pops up when someone starts signing but I need to prevent the program from being closed.

Here is what I tried that seems to have failed

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    //reset hardware
    e.Cancel = true;
    sigPlusNET1.LCDRefresh(0, 0, 0, 240, 64);
    sigPlusNET1.LCDSetWindow(0, 0, 240, 64);
    sigPlusNET1.SetSigWindow(1, 0, 0, 240, 64);
    sigPlusNET1.KeyPadClearHotSpotList();
    sigPlusNET1.SetLCDCaptureMode(1);
    sigPlusNET1.SetTabletState(0);
    this.Hide();

}
```

Any Ideas?

Edit: With this code, the app closes normally and does not hide.

Here is the section that works just fine:

```
// Ok Button
private void cmdClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //cmdSaveImage_Click(sender, e);
    this.Visible = false;
    sigPlusNET1.KeyPadClearHotSpotList();
    sigPlusNET1.ClearTablet();
    sigPlusNET1.KeyPadAddHotSpot(0, 1, 0, 0, 1000, 1000);
    progTimer.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: How exactly is it failing? Is the application closing anyway?

Comment: @Justin Niessner Yes, the form just closes, it seems to ignore it.

Comment: Just to know: with Hide you mean minimize... I am right ?

Comment: No, the window and the task item should disappear. This happens elsewhere just fine(when the signature is accepted)

Comment: If you create a simple app that just does the cancel and the hide it works as expected (i.e. the form is hidden but the app continues to run).  Are you sure the app is shutting down?  If it is, the problem is not in this function.

Comment: It should work. Maybe its not connected to your form correctly.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in Form1_FormClosing() - does your application hit it? If not, then your events are not wired right.

Comment: paste your code here: http://pastebin.com/ so we can look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that `Form1_FormClosing` is specified in the form properties as the handler of the `FormClosing` event.

Alternatively, you can override the actual method itself.

```
    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        base.OnClosing(e);
    }
```

Comment: That worked!
    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.visable = false;
        base.OnClosing(e);
    }

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you [hide the window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375998/how-to-prevent-closing-of-a-hidden-form-in-c).
Perhaps it would work if you would just minimize it.

Comment: I hide the window elsewhere without any issues at all.

Comment: Hiding the form is ok as long as it isn't closed as well.